# Close Mailchimp popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, mailchimp

I've tried code from answers in 2014 and 2015 but they didn't seem to work. In devtools, the first few lines of popup markup looks like this:

```
<div widgetid="SignupForm_0" id="SignupForm_0" class="modalContent">
<div class="flash-block" data-dojo-attach-point="formResponseMessages"></div>
<div class="modalContent__content" data-dojo-attach-point="formContentContainer">
```

I want the user to be able to click anywhere on the page to close the popup, not only on the close button. The button markup looks like this:

```
    <div class="mc-closeModal" data-action="close-mc-modal" data-dojo-attach-point="modalClose">close</div>
```

I've tried these kinds of hacks to no avail:

```
$('body').on('click', function () {
  $('#SignupForm_0').trigger('popmakeSetCookie').popmake('close');
});
```

or

```
$('body').on('click', function () {
  $('#SignupForm_0').hide();
});
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What about `$('#SignupForm_0').css({"display":"none"});`? Also, how are you applying this JS inside the Mailchimp page?

Comment: Doesn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 0):

Had the wrong ID, stupid me...

```
$("#PopupSignupForm_0").remove();
```